# Displaying get_context_data in template Django

Tags: django, orm

I am trying to display the get_context_data on the template. I have a method on the model class that I need to call from ProfileView which has two different models. For the Profile View I have Profile Model and for the shippingaddress view I have ShippingAddress Model. And these models are from two different app. I tried the function below and it does not show any error, but when I tried to call it in the Template, It does not show the method.

**Views.py**

```
class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = "account/profile.html"
    success_url = "/"
    
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['shipping'] = ShippingAddress.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return context
```

Template code

```
{{object.get_full_address}}
```

Models.py

```
class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=True, blank=True)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
    
    def get_phone_number(self):
        return self.phone_number
    
    @property  
    def get_full_address(self):
        return f"{self.street_address}, {self.province}, {self.city}, {self.country}, {self.zip_code}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object` is the context variable that `DetailView` will add to the context. For your view this would be an instance of `Profile`. You pass a queryset into the context with the name `shipping` so you can loop over that:

```
{% for shipping_address in shipping %}
    {{ shipping_address.get_full_address }}
{% endfor %}
```

> **Note**: You need to loop because one user has multiple Shipping Addresses according to your models.

> **Note**: Also you didn't need to override `get_context_data` you could simply have written:
>
> ```
> {% for shipping_address in request.user.shippingaddress_set %}
>     {{ shipping_address.get_full_address }}
> {% endfor %}
> ```
>
> Where `shippingaddress_set` is the related model name with `_set`
> appended. You can change that by setting `related_name` on your
> foreign key.

Comment: It works. Thank you. I am also trying the related_name for the foreign key. Just a question, What would be the best approach here and why?

Comment: @ian I would prefer using the `related_name` to get the related instances because simply it is the same result in less lines of code. There are places where one would write a query specifically, for e.g. if one wants to get the shipping addresses of multiple users we would write a query using `prefetch_related` to decrease the number of queries made to the database (else we would be making a query to get the addresses for **each** user, meaning n queries for n users).